# How do I store 1 INT into another or have it stored somewhere so it updates every time the script finishes?

Tags: c++

My script is below for a project I'm working on as I learn/practice.

1. I'd like to know how to keep track of the **health**. It seems, currently I'm just adding/subtracting/keeping it the same but the system has no no where to actually record the health and I'm not sure how to do it.
2. Also, what am I doing wrong as I tried to make the script repeat once it's finished but instead, it gives me a blank space instead of giving the Attack/Defend/Heal options again.

I tried the "do" + "while" conditions so **DO** this script **WHILE** the health is above 0 ---it works (kind of). The script doesn't end which is an improvement BUT it doesn't repeat the Attack/Defend/Heal menu.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std; 

int main()  {

    int health = 50;
    int Attack = 1;
    int Defend = 2;
    int Heal = 3;
    do {
        std::cout << "Please select an option: " << endl;
        std::cout << "1. Attack" << endl;
        std::cout << "2. Defend" << endl;
        std::cout << "3. Heal" << endl;

        int  Move;
        std::cin >> Move;

        if (Move == 1) {
            std::cout << "You did 1 damage" << endl;
            std::cout << "You lost 1 health" << endl;
            // while (health - 1)
            std: cout << "Your current health is: " << health -1 << endl;
            while (health > 0);
        }
        if (Move == 2) {
            std::cout << "You took no damage" << endl;
            std::cout << "You lost 0 health" << endl;
            cout << "Your current health is: " << health << endl;
        }
        if (Move == 3) {
            std::cout << "You gained 1 health" << endl;
            cout << "Your current health is: " << health +1 << endl;
        }
    }
    while (health > 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the first `while (health > 0);`, that what's called an *infinite loop* and that is what is giving you the 'blank space'.

The second `while (health > 0);` is fine because that is the last part of the `do .. while` loop.

Secondly to store the new health you have to use the `health` variable. You must assign the new value to this variable, just like you assigned the initial value of `50`. E.g.

```
// assign new health value
health = health - 1;
// display new health value
std::cout << "Your current health is: " << health << std::endl;
```